# C# ASP.Net MVC: RedirectFromLoginPage always goes to default url, and not to returnurl

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, forms-authentication

I have an MVC4 application with Membership logon (through FormsAuthentication).

This is defined in web.config as follows.
My default url is home root (~/):

```
<roleManager enabled="true" />
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms defaultUrl="~" loginUrl="~/Account" />
</authentication>
```

In my AccountController in the Login post method, following code is relevant.
This code is executed when the user clicks on the login with valid credentials.

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(creds.Username, creds.Password))
{
    FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(creds.Username, false);
    return null;
}
```

Now, if I'm navigating (anonymously) to: ~/Admin, I get redirected to ~/Account to log in, which is perfect. I can see that the url is formed as follows:

```
http://localhost:23759/Account?ReturnUrl=%2fAdmin
```

But, when I succesfully login, I get redirected to home (~/) instead of ~/Admin

Please help! 
Many thanks!

**Edit: Found the actual issue: it was the post method that wasn't receiving the querystring**

Comment: From the MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ka5ffkce.aspx): "If the ReturnURL variable does not exist, the RedirectFromLoginPage method redirects to the URL in the DefaultUrl property."  Looks like .NET doesn't know Admin exists.  Maybe the slash (%2f) is causing the issue?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I found the solution!
Thanks to FlopScientist, who got me thinking further.

It was indeed because I was doing a **POST method**, which did not take the QueryString from the **GET** into account.

First I had this in my View:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Account")
{
    <div class="LoginBox">
    //Etc...
    </div>
}
```

I have updated it to following:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Account", new { ReturnUrl = Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] }, FormMethod.Post))
{
    //Etc...
}
```

Now I can actually see a querystring in my debug and I do get a correct redirect!

Comment: Glad to know I helped you

Answer (score 4):

There doesn't seems any issue with your Return URL: [ %2f is `/` ] `localhost:23759/Account?ReturnUrl=%2fAdmin`

So, what remains is to do some checks as to what is causing such behaviour.

**1.)** Are you sure that the return page as specified in the return url:

```
localhost...?ReturnUrl=%2fAdmin
```

actually exists and your user has access to it?Here Admin is a folder, so you must have a page `default.aspx` inside this folder. If it does not exists, `RedirectFromLoginPage` by default will send you to `DefaultURL`.

**2.)** Also, Try using ***[FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.formsauthentication.getredirecturl%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)*** method to see what happens.

```
if (Membership.ValidateUser(creds.Username, creds.Password))
{
    Response.Redirect(FormsAuthentication.GetRedirectUrl(username, false));
}
```

**3.)** OR does this works ? [ Recommended for debug purposes ]

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"]))
{
    Response.Redirect("~/Admin");
}
```

Lastly make sure there are NO such code lines redirecting user to other pages/DefaultURL.

Comment: I have updated my question with my findings to get better formatting.

Answer (score 2):

It probably because that path is not detected as same app path:

> By default, the ReturnUrl variable must refer to a page within the
>   current application. If ReturnUrl refers to a page in a different
>   application or on a different server, the RedirectFromLoginPage method
>   redirects to the URL in the DefaultUrl property. If you want to allow
>   redirects to a page outside the current application, you must set the
>   EnableCrossAppRedirects property to true using the
>   enableCrossAppRedirects attribute of the forms configuration element.

from: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/1f5z1yty.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. As stated in my question (updated), there seems to be something wrong with the querystring...